# CMU Sphinx-4 tutorial: can't locate resource

Tags: cmusphinx

I am trying to follow the Sphinx-4 tutorial at:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Doing precisely what it says, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" Property exception component:'acousticModelLoader' property:'location' - Can't locate resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz
```

I assumed the sphinx4-data dependency would provide the necessary models, but either the tutorial is incorrect or this is not the case. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used maven to retrieve sphinx4-data or if you checked out code from trunk, the resource path for the acoustic model must be `resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/acoustic/wsj`

You can look on sphinx4 demos for details